# How is it possible to set a TextView under a other optjek, like a Button, in the JAVA file?

Tags: textview, android

is it possible to set a TextView in the Java file to a defined place?
This is my xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layoutebusbaum"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".EbusBaum" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Anzahl an Funktionsfeldern"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText03"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Anzahl an Parameterwerten"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EditText03"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Anzahl an Funktionparameter"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="generate"
    android:text="Generieren" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and now i wanna set a TextView, on the onClick event from the button, under the button!! 
here is my java code:

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Ebusbaum extends Activity {

Integer run1 = 0;
Integer run2 = 0;
Integer run3 = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_ebusbaum);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ebusbaum, menu);
    return true;
}

public void generate(View Conect){

    EditText anz1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    String anz11 = anz1.getText().toString();
    Integer Anzahl1 = Integer.parseInt(anz11);

    EditText anz2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
    String anz22 = anz2.getText().toString();
    Integer Anzahl2 = Integer.parseInt(anz22);

    EditText anz3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText03);
    String anz33 = anz3.getText().toString();
    Integer Anzahl3 = Integer.parseInt(anz33);

    //Here i like to creat the Textview, but i dont know how!
}   
}
```

Is there someone who can help me? i searched in the internet and found some code exampels but my App doest work with these exampels. Im using android API 11.

Answer (score 0):

Below the button insert your textview and hide it

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/EditText02"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:onClick="generate"
android:text="Generieren" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtYourTextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_below="@+id/button1" 
android:visibility="invisible"
/>
```

On OnClick Event show the textView.

```
TextView btextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtYourTextView);
btextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btextView.setText("yourText");
```

It Should Work.

Comment: oh yes this one i know! but the problem is, i like to creat a vriable tree view! i tryed it with the ExpandableList but at the end this treelist shoud be variable and shoud work wiht 4 levels... An that was to complicatet for me.. so i decided to make my own variabel tree only whith TextView! Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: sorry i couldn't get the point.. what you trying to do actually?

Comment: i like to creat a tree structure wiht about 4 levels

Comment: what you mean tree structure about 4 levels? could you elaborate it

Comment: your answer is in your link itself you can find the source code for what your expecting try that source code